# MySQL change query result based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running mariaDB version of mysql and my query result is following

```
select count(*) as 'Non-HT Computes', vcpus_used as 'Status'
from compute_nodes
WHERE deleted_at is NULL
  AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%'
  AND vcpus < '21'
GROUP BY vcpus_used

+-----------------+--------+
| Non-HT Computes | Status |
+-----------------+--------+
|              20 |      0 |
|               5 |     16 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

This is what i am trying to do if in `Status` column value is `0` then print `Available` and if value is between `16` to `20` print value `In-used`, how do i alter result of return values on fly?

Final result should be look like

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| Non-HT Computes |      Status    |
+-----------------+----------------+
|              20 |     Available  |
|               5 |     In-Used    |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

I have tried `CASE` statement but not sure how do i put it together with alias `Status` column, because `Status` is pseudo column.

Edit:

I got this far but not able to find out how to print `Non-HT Computes` table :(

```
select CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 'available' ELSE 'In-used' END AS Status from (select count(*) as 'Non-HT Computes',vcpus_used as 'Status' from compute_nodes WHERE deleted_at is NULL AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%' AND vcpus < '21' GROUP BY vcpus_used) as a
+-----------+
| Status    |
+-----------+
| available |
| In-used   |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Hint:  Use a  `CASE` expression.

Comment: As i mentioned i did tried `CASE WHEN` condition but somehow it throwing error and i believe its `Status` column issue because i have generate that column name by `AS`, I think i am struggling with syntax issue here..

Comment: what if they are not 0 or between 16-20

Comment: They are fixed,  either `0` ro `16` or `20` or i think we can use (non-zero also), greater than zero would be good choice. i made little progress but not able to print `Non-HT Computes ` table, I did `select CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 'available' ELSE 'Donno' END AS Status from (select count(*) as 'Non-HT Computes',vcpus_used as 'Status' from compute_nodes WHERE deleted_at is NULL AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%' AND vcpus < '21' GROUP BY vcpus_used) as a`

Comment: It would be good to know why `negative` vote on question?  if its low quality question then i can agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may do the work. If you want to limit after non-zero cases you may use `having` statement.

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Non-HT Computes',
       CASE
           WHEN vcpus_used BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN "In-used"
           WHEN vcpus_used = 0 THEN "Available"
           ELSE "Non-Zero"
           END AS Status
FROM compute_nodes
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%'
  AND vcpus < '21'
GROUP BY vcpus_used;
```

Answer (score 2):

First option is to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Non-HT Computes',
       CASE
           WHEN vcpus_used = 0 THEN 'Available'
           WHEN vcpus_used >= 16 AND vcpus_used <= 20 THEN 'In-use'
       END  AS 'Status'
FROM compute_nodes
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%'
  AND vcpus < '21'
GROUP BY vcpus_used
```

Second option would be to create a table that has the status values (0, 16, 20) and join against that table.

```
CREATE TABLE status_text (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    descr VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO status_text VALUES (0,'Available');
INSERT INTO status_text VALUES (16,'In-use');
INSERT INTO status_text VALUES (20,'In-use');

SELECT count(*) AS 'Non-HT Computes',descr AS status
FROM compute_nodes
JOIN status_text ON (id=vcpus_used) 
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND hypervisor_hostname LIKE '%sriov%'
  AND vcpus < '21'
GROUP BY vcpus_used
```